# learning $\mathbf{A}^1$-homotopy theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

If you wanted to learn $\mathbf{A}^1$-homotopy theory, which sources in which order would you use?

Comment: It of course depends on what you know.  If you don't have substantial experience with model categories and simplicial sets, they are prerequisites to $\mathbf{A}^1$ homotopy theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A book that might be helpful, that is probably mentioned on website above is [http://www.amazon.com/Motivic-Homotopy-Theory-Nordfjordeid-Universitext/dp/3540458956/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303257360&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540458956)

Also, people now call it Motivic instead of $\mathbb{A}^1$ sometimes.

Answer (score 9):

Dan Dugger's paper on the subject is an extremely valuable reference, since he manages to set up the foundations in a natural manner.  Some familiarity with model categories is certainly needed.  A version is available on his web page:

http://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/univ.html

Of course the long Morel-Voevodsky paper is the original reference.  It has a lot of good information, although I did not find it easy going.

Answer (score 5):

Aravind Asok has an entire website devoted to pointing out resources for learning $\mathbf{A}^1$-homotopy theory.  It is organized quite well.  The concept list section of the page has lots of wikipedia-like entries on topics related to $\mathbf{A}^1$-homotopy theory.

http://a1homotopy.tiddlyspot.com/